# Learning how to use Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to learn testing with Jest and Enzyme and I wrote this test that is not passing. I'm getting two UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarnings: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` and `nhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)`

My mock error is 
`Expected mock function to have been called with:
      ["hot dog"]
    But it was not called.`

My test is for searching a food api and it returning a list of recipes.

```
describe("<GetRecipe />", () => {
const filler: any = null;

it("Should call searchRecipe with the appropriate recipe", () => {
const food = "hot dog";
const searchRecipe = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(
  <GetRecipe
    search={"hot dog"}
    recipes={[filler]}
    searchRecipe={searchRecipe}
  />
);

const button = wrapper.find("#getRecipe");
button.simulate("click");
expect(searchRecipe).toBeCalledWith(food);
 });
});
```

And the function I'm testing is

```
public searchRecipe = async (e: any) => {
e.preventDefault();
const { search } = this.state;
const res = await axios.get(
  `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${search}&app_id=${APID}&app_key=${APIKEY}&from=0&to=21`
);
console.log(res.data.hits);
this.setState({
  recipes: res.data.hits
 });
};
```

Comment: can you share the code for `GetRecipe`?

Comment: the function I posted `searchRecipe` is not what you need or do you need more?

Comment: You are passing a mock function (`searchRecipe`) to `GetRecipe` as a prop, simulating a click, then checking to see if the mock function was called with `food`.  I am assuming that the click handler for `#getRecipe` calls `searchRecipe` and you are trying to verify this behavior by spying on `searchRecipe`, but I can't tell that for sure or give accurate feedback without seeing `GetRecipe`.